# Magento 2.4 Add Recaptcha in Custom From

Tags: magento2.4, recaptcha

**Magento 2.4**

How to add Google Recaptcha in Custom Form ?

Comment: check this link - https://meetanshi.com/blog/add-google-recaptcha-to-magento-2/

Comment: @MohitPatel This is not right way to add Google Recaptcha in Custom Form. I am looking for a Magento's way. how Magento use this. That Method i want to use.

Comment: You want to using custom module??

Comment: Yes i i have Custom Module and Custom Form.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Module Name : **VendoreName_DemoRecaptcha**

**app/code/VendoreName/DemoRecaptcha**

**registration.php**

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'VendoreName_DemoRecaptcha',
    __DIR__
);
```

**app/code/VendoreName/DemoRecaptcha/etc**

**module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="VendoreName_DemoRecaptcha" setup_version="1.0.0">
    </module>
</config>
```

**app/code/VendoreName/DemoRecaptcha/etc/adminhtml**

**system.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <section id="recaptcha_frontend">
            <group id="type_for">
                <field id="customform" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="140" showInDefault="1"
                       showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0" canRestore="1">
                    <label>Enable for Custom Form</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\ReCaptchaAdminUi\Model\OptionSource\Type</source_model>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

**app/code/VendoreName/DemoRecaptcha/etc**

**config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
    <default>
        <recaptcha_frontend>
            <type_for>
                <customform/>
            </type_for>
        </recaptcha_frontend>
    </default>
</config>
```

**app/code/VendoreName/DemoRecaptcha/etc/frontend**

**routes.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route frontName="demorecaptcha" id="demorecaptcha">
            <module name="VendoreName_DemoRecaptcha"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

**app/code/VendoreName/DemoRecaptcha/etc/frontend**

**events.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">

    <event name="controller_action_predispatch_demorecaptcha_index_save">
        <observer name="recaptcha_demo_form" instance="VendoreName\DemoRecaptcha\Observer\RecapchaFormObserver"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

**app/code/VendoreName/DemoRecaptcha/Observer**

**RecapchaFormObserver.php**

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace VendoreName\DemoRecaptcha\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;
use Magento\ReCaptchaUi\Model\IsCaptchaEnabledInterface;
use Magento\ReCaptchaUi\Model\RequestHandlerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface;

class RecapchaFormObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $redirect;
    private $url;
    private $isCaptchaEnabled;
    private $requestHandler;

    public function __construct(
        UrlInterface $url,
        IsCaptchaEnabledInterface $isCaptchaEnabled,
        RequestHandlerInterface $requestHandler,
        RedirectInterface $redirect
    ) {
        $this->url = $url;
        $this->isCaptchaEnabled = $isCaptchaEnabled;
        $this->requestHandler = $requestHandler;
        $this->redirect = $redirect;
    }

    public function execute(Observer $observer): void
    {
        $key = 'customform';
        if ($this->isCaptchaEnabled->isCaptchaEnabledFor($key)) {
            /** @var Action $controller */
            $controller = $observer->getControllerAction();
            $request = $controller->getRequest();
            $response = $controller->getResponse();
            $redirectOnFailureUrl = $this->redirect->getRedirectUrl();
            $this->requestHandler->execute($key, $request, $response, $redirectOnFailureUrl);
        }
    }
}
```

**app/code/VendoreName/DemoRecaptcha/Controller/Index**

**Index.php**

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\DemoRecaptcha\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Session;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    /**
     * @var PageFactory
     */
    protected $resultPageFactory;
    /**
     * @var Session
     */
    protected $customerSession;
    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     * @param Session $customerSession
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
        Session $customerSession
    ) {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->set(__('Recaptcha Demo'));
        return $resultPage;
    }
}
```

**app/code/VendoreName/DemoRecaptcha/Controller/Index**

**Save.php**

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\DemoRecaptcha\Controller\Index;

class Save extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $_request;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request
    ) {
        $this->_request = $request;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
    public function execute()
    {
        echo "<pre>";
        $data = $this->_request->getPostValue();
        print_r($data);
        echo "save you data here";
        exit();
    } // main Executtion function
}
```

**app/code/VendoreName/DemoRecaptcha/view/frontend/layout**

**demorecaptcha_index_index.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">

  <body>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
          <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template"
                 name="demo.for.recaptcha"
                 template="VendoreName_DemoRecaptcha::form.phtml"
                 >
                <container name="form.additional.info.demo.for.recaptcha">
                  <block class="Magento\ReCaptchaUi\Block\ReCaptcha"
                         name="recaptcha"
                         after="-"
                         template="Magento_ReCaptchaFrontendUi::recaptcha.phtml"
                         ifconfig="recaptcha_frontend/type_for/customform">
                      <arguments>
                          <argument name="recaptcha_for" xsi:type="string">customform</argument>
                          <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                              <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                                  <item name="recaptcha" xsi:type="array">
                                      <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_ReCaptchaFrontendUi/js/reCaptcha</item>
                                  </item>
                              </item>
                          </argument>
                      </arguments>
                  </block>
                </container>
          </block>
    </referenceContainer>
  </body>
</page>
```

**app/code/VendoreName/DemoRecaptcha/view/frontend/templates**

**form.phtml**

```
<?php

$form_url = $this->getUrl('demorecaptcha/index/save');
?>
<div id="modal-call-for-price">
    <div class="modal-body">
        <form class="form"
            action="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($form_url) ?>"
            id="demo-recaptcha-form"
            method="post"
            enctype='multipart/form-data'
            autocomplete="off">
            <input type="hidden" name="product_id" >
            <fieldset class="fieldset">
                <div class="field required">
                    <label for="user_name" class="label">
                      <span><?= $block->escapeHtml('Name:') ?></span>
                    </label>
                    <div class="control">
                        <input type="text"
                               name="customer_name"
                               title="<?= $block->escapeHtml('Name') ?>"
                               class="input-text"
                               data-validate="{required:true}">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="field required">
                    <label for="user_name" class="label">
                      <span><?= $block->escapeHtml('E-mail:') ?></span>
                    </label>
                    <div class="control">
                        <input type="email"
                               name="customer_email"
                               title="<?= $block->escapeHtml('E-mail') ?>"
                               class="input-text"
                               data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-email':true}">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?= $block->getChildHtml('form.additional.info.demo.for.recaptcha') ?>
           </fieldset>
            <div class="actions-toolbar">
                <div class="primary">
                    <button type="submit"
                            class="action submit primary "
                            title="<?= $block->escapeHtml('Submit') ?>">
                              <span>
                                <?= $block->escapeHtml('Submit') ?>
                              </span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
        <script type="text/x-magento-init">
          {
              "#demo-recaptcha-form": {
                  "validation": {}
              }
          }
        </script>
    </div>
</div>
```

***Note:- You must have Recaptcha key which put on Configuration -> Security -> Google reCAPTCHA Storefront And you must enable it below this configuration at Storefront section Otherwise Recaptcha  is not show.***

Comment: app/code/VendoreName/DemoRecaptcha/view/frontend/layout/form.phtml should be app/code/VendoreName/DemoRecaptcha/view/frontend/templates/form.phtml

rest seems good will check to confirm output

Comment: @zuberbandi Thanks i update answer.

Comment: @Msquare i have followed the same way for adding a recpatcha in my custom form and ir's working fine for recapcta V2 but facing the issue in recapcha invisible V3 .. can you please help ??

Comment: Please ask a new question with your code and what is your requirement. and share your question link.