# How to implement reCAPTCH V3 in custom form in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, php, magento2.4.2, google-recaptcha

By using Magento default functionality i am able to implement reCAPTCHA V3 in login form and registration form.But i also need that in one of my custom form. Is there any way to implement reCAPTCHA v3 on custom from page in phtml file.what is the Magento way to implement this.
thanks

Comment: try this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/322149/82670

Comment: Hi, @Msquare that is working fine with V2 but it is not working fine with invisible V3 .Can you please give an explanation on how to add invisible V3 in custom form.

Answer (score -1):

Check the below link to implement reCAPTCHA V3 -

https://amasty.com/knowledge-base/how-to-implement-recaptcha-v3-in-magento-2.html