# How to add google recaptcha V3 for custom forms in magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3, magento2.2

I have around 20 popup custom forms in my magento 2. I want to add Google recaptcha V3 for the all popup forms.

How can i add captcha v3 to all the forms. what is the best way to add for all the custom forms in magento 2.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> You need to implement this code: [Magento 2.4 Add Recaptcha in Custom From](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/320488/magento-2-4-add-recaptcha-in-custom-from)

> **And then you need to follow the below actions.**

1. Add your action event in the **events.xml** file.
2. Update your layout file like **demorecaptcha_index_index.xml**
3. Call Recaptcha using getchildHtml like **form.phtml**

Comment: HI @Msquare, thanks for your responce. So here for each form i need to create new observer right?

Comment: No @Mani, You need to add a new event and used the same observer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check this link codes which how to add Google Recaptcha in Custom form explained.

**https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/133432/85907**

In above link Very detailed explained.

**https://github.com/mageplaza/magento-2-google-recaptcha**

Above link is third party module and that module provides add google recaptcha functionality custom form.

Let me know if any query.

**`THANKS.`**